SOLR 504 - bad gateway
When trying to reindex SOLR, at some point I only get failed tasks in my resque:queue. I try to retry them, but after 60 seconds (default bad gateway time imposed by ALB) I receive error 504. What should I change to fix it?
SOLR_JAVA_MEM: -Xms24g -Xmx24g
I use t3.2xlarge instance.
I tried to modify BATCH_SOLR_SIZE from 1000 to 700, then to 100 - no idea, almost often the same issue.
solrconfig:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>7.1.0</luceneMatchVersion>
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>
  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
  
  <indexConfig>
    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>
    <infoStream>true</infoStream>
  </indexConfig>
  
  <jmx/>
  
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>
    <autoCommit>
      <maxTime>25000</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>
    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>10000</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>
  </updateHandler>
  
  <query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="1024" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="1024" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="1024" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
    <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
    <maxWarmingSearchers>5</maxWarmingSearchers>
  </query>
  
  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"/>
    <httpCaching never304="true"/>
  </requestDispatcher>
  
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="q.op">AND</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">text</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>
</config>


